# Fluentd can't upload buffer file to s3 when every hour on the hour

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, fluentd

[image: This is my fluentd log folder]
[image: this is my fluend conf file]

Hi everyone:
    I use fluentd collect my log and these log are generated by my python program, so use forward as the source parameter. But the file that be generated on every hour on the hour will be leaved on the machine which the fluentd running and sometimes there will accumulate some files that can't upload s3. When I restart the fluentd these files except that generated on every hour on the hour will be continued uploaded to s3， that' fine, but how can I deal with these unuploaded files? I searched Google, but can't find a good method, who can help me, thank you!

=================
Update
If possible I want to deal with the problem of the accumulating of files, why they don't upload to s3, I use AWS's EC2 and S3 in same region and same VPC.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that a subset of buffer files fail to get uploaded even if you restart Fluentd? If so, can you also share your Fluentd log?

Comment: Hi, Let me offer an alternative solution, you can use the [aws-logging-handlers](https://github.com/omrikiei/aws_logging_handlers) package to directly upload log records to s3
installation vie pypi:
`pip install aws-logging-handlers`